# identify freed object when os shutdown the app

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

an android app have a thread that execute c++ code.
the android OS can shut down the app and a pointer become dangled, it causes rare crashes that I could not reproduce.

is there a solution to identify such issue?

for example will this work ?

checking if the pointer `main_class == MainClass::instance` in sensitive points in the app logic

**mainclass.h**

```
class MainClass
{
public:
    MainClass();
    ~MainClass();

    static MainClass* instance;

    void DoWork();
    bool Finished();
}
```

**mainclass.cpp**

```
MainClass* MainClass::instance = nullptr;

MainClass::MainClass()
{
    instance = this;
}

MainClass::~MainClass(){}
void MainClass::DoWork(){}
bool MainClass::Finished()
{
    return false;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    MainClass* main_class = new(std::nothrow) MainClass();

    if (main_class == nullptr)
    { 
        return 0; 
    }

    while(main_class->Finished() == false)
    {
        main_class->DoWork();
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It seems like you want `MainClass` to be a singleton. Unfortunately you can create any number of `MainClass` instances, and each created instance will overwrite the `instance` member, so it's not really a true singleton.

Comment: On another unrelated note, returning zero from the `main` function is usually considered "all okay, no errors", while a small positive number is "error".

Comment: you are right but the only place that it get created is in the start of the main function

Comment: _"the android OS can shut down the app and a pointer become dangled"_ Which scenario are you talking about here? If the OS shuts down your app's entire process, then how does anything dangle? Are you saying only parts of the app gets shut down? If so, which parts, and how do they correspond to your code?

Comment: @Michael i do know that it can release the opengl texture/whole context without shutting down the app, unfortunately im not familiar with the way android release other resources of background apps when it require memory.